# stream redirection order and what os perform in details

Tags: linux, bash

What is the difference of this two bash commands:
1. printf "somthing wrong!%v" Oops! > dumpz 2>&1
2. printf "somthing wrong!%v" Oops! 2>&1 > dumpz
When i use first script both streams are saved in file(dumpz).
When i use the second script only stdout goes in file and stderr is displayed in terminal.

Another question is why in first script the sequence of streams is incorrect.I mean first line of file contains stderr and second line contains stdout.
I need some help about what really done in background to this streams. I mean what OS really perform.(pointers, memory, etc).

Comment: It's not so bad to [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29), at least *once in a while*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order is pretty important in these redirections.

```
printf "somthing wrong!%v" Oops! > dumpz 2>&1
```

will redirect stdout to `dumpz` file and then redirect stderr to wherever stdout is redirected.

But this command:

```
printf "somthing wrong!%v" Oops! 2>&1 > dumpz
```

will first redirect stderr to wherever stdout is redirected (tty or terminal) and then redirect stdout to `dumpz` file .

Comment: so what about incorrect sequence, when i use first command file contains stderr in first line and stdout in second line.

Comment: Don't get your question. Are you talking about this command: `2>&1 > dumpz `?

Comment: i'm talking about printf "somthing wrong!%v" Oops! > dumpz 2>&1

Comment: correct command is: **`printf 'somthing wrong!%s' 'Oops!' > dumpz 2>&1`**

Comment: i'm talking about printf "somthing wrong!%v" Oops! > dumpz 2>&1
when i run this command the file look like below:
bash: printf: `v': invalid format character
somthing wrong!
as u see first line is represents stderr and second line represents stdout
but in command we first redirect stdout to file and then stderr is redirected to stdout! I mean in file streams are disordered.
didn't you think so?

Comment: No the real problem is use of `!` in double quote OR without quotes. BASH interprets it as you're trying to run a past event. Try running with single quotes and will see it behaving nicely: **`printf 'somthing wrong!%v' 'Oops!' > dumpz 2>&1`**

Answer (score 4):

The application of the redirections happens in the order you specify, so in the first case

```
printf "somthing wrong!%v" Oops! > dumpz 2>&1
```

it is first redirecting stdout to the file, then redirecting stderr to whatever stdout is directed to, which is the file.

In the second case

```
printf "somthing wrong!%v" Oops! 2>&1 > dumpz
```

it is first redirecting stderr to whatever stdout is directed to (currently the terminal).  Then it redirects stdout to the file.

Comment: so what about incorrect sequence, when i use first command file contains stderr in first line and stdout in second line.

Comment: [Here is](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/) very nice explanation (with pictures) of what is really going on during executing both versions of given examples.